Log4j2 no persiste los logueos en SQLITE con un appender de tipo JDBC
Tengo un projecto de una app pequeña que guarda su estado en una base SQLITE, estoy usando maven y spring-boot. No he tenido problemas con la persistencia de las entidades (uso Spring Data JPA), pero no logro que log4j2 persista en la base. La base consiste de un archivo llamado data.db y se encuentra en la misma carpeta del proyecto. Cuando corro el proyecto lo hago desde esta carpeta tras haber ejecutado mvn clean package.
Mi archivo de configuración (log4j2.xml) que está guardado en la carpeta de recursos (src/main/resources) es este, supuse que al ser una base de datos embedida, da lo mismo hacer o no pooling, con lo cual usé la opción de configuración mas sencilla pero desaconsejada para bases de datos grandes. He tratado de seguir la documentación, pero tal vez me he equivocado:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" name="config">
    <Appenders>
        <JDBC name="database" tableName="APPLICATION_LOG">
            <DriverManager>
                <connectionString>jdbc:sqlite:data.db</connectionString>
                <driverClassName>org.sqlite.JDBC</driverClassName>
            </DriverManager>
            <Column name="EVENT_ID" literal="NULL" />
            <Column name="EVENT_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />
            <Column name="LEVEL" pattern="%level" />
            <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" />
            <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
            <Column name="THROWABLE" pattern="%ex{full}" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="database" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>


La version de Java que estoy usando es la 21 y la jvm es la de Semeru para windows.
En el POM he traido las siguientes dependencias relacionadas a JDBC, SQLITE y Log4j2 :
        <!--log4j api-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--log4j core engine-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--sqlite jdbc driver-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--community-dialects-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
        </dependency>


No aparecen las versiones ya que entiendo que el POM padre, que viene provisto por el spring initializr, las tiene ya configuradas:

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>


El esquema de la tabla donde supuestamente deberían persistirse los logueos es este:

CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_LOG ( EVENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EVENT_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, LEVEL TEXT, LOGGER TEXT, MESSAGE TEXT, THROWABLE TEXT);


La app funciona, pero no logro que se persistan los logueos, puede ser que esté configurando mal? que falte algo?
